# Unable to revoke permissions for 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions

I have tried everything I know to do and spent several hours Googling without success. I want to revoke the `SHUTDOWN` and `CONTROL SERVER` permissions for the login `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

When I run this

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL,NULL)
REVERT
```

...the output is:

[image]

Things I have tried:

Deleting the Login entirely, 
Executing the following (with the different permissions listed):

```
USE master;  
REVOKE SHUTDOWN FROM "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM";
GO
```

Even after I delete the login, and execute the `fn_my_permissions` SP, it still lists the permissions from the image above.

Any help I could get on this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This should revoke the permissions**

```
REVOKE CONTROL SERVER TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
REVOKE SHUTDOWN TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
```

---

**Tests**

```
use [master]
GO
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
GO
use [master]
GO
GRANT SHUTDOWN TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
GO

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL,NULL)
REVERT
```

**Result**

[image]

*... (34 Results)*

```
REVOKE CONTROL SERVER TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
REVOKE SHUTDOWN TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL,NULL)
REVERT
```

**Result**

[image]

---

**Extra info**

If you are ever unsure about the syntax, an easy one (in my opinion), is selecting what you need inside of the GUI and then scripting it out using the 'script' button.

For example in this answer, I added the grants for the `CONTROL SERVER` and `SHUTDOWN` to the login `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` , Scripted it out, and then removed them in the GUI and scripted them out again to get the revoke statements.
I am against executing stuff through the GUI though, since it is easy to overlook things, and it has proven to be buggy.

[image]

Comment: When I run those commands, the permissions still show for me... running the command as 'sa'.. any other ideas? This is wierd.

Comment: What does this do: 
REVOKE CONTROL SERVER TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] CASCADE
REVOKE SHUTDOWN TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] CASCADE

Comment: Good tip on using the GUI, thanks. Adding CASCADE to the commands didn't seem to have an effect..

Comment: @Jordan No problem, glad you found it useful!  Silly question, but does the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM have any server wide or other permissions that could give him these rights? I was a bit fast to mention cascade, I only did because I got an error message, but should not have helped if you aren't getting any.

Comment: I checked - SYSTEM is not a member of the local administrators group, or a member of the sysadmin server role (or any role)!

Comment: It doesn't look like it. When you look at the securables screen in the GUI, the only thing checked is 'Connect to SQL'

Comment: @Jordan Hmm, also not a part of any other groups that might grant him more privileges? What does this return:  EXEC xp_logininfo 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM','all';
You could also try explicitly denying the permissions...

Comment: That was it, someone put the administrators group in as a sysadmiin role and I didn't see it until I ran your last command. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan awesome, no problem, have a good one!